# Help with jQuery validate and a Zip code restriction based on the 1st three digitss

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I am assuming I need a regular expression here?

I have a zip code field and the zip codes must be in the city limits of Chicago. Luckily all the zip codes begin with 606. So I need to poll the input to make sure that the zip code entered is 5 digits and begin with the numbers 606:

My input is basic enough:

```
<label for="dzip"><span class="red">&hearts;&nbsp;</span>Zip:</label>
<input name="attributes[address_zip]" id="dzip" type="text" size="30" class="required zip-code" />
```

And then my script for city was easy enough. I just need to apply it to zip-code as well:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("Chicago", function(value) {
    return value == "Chicago";
}, '**Recipient must reside in Chicago City Limits**');
```

May help if I show how the plug-in functions for phone-numbers (US). Basically I need to translate this to zips:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 && phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

What does this part do/mean?:

```
phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "")
```

I dropped in the phone part directly from an example on the validate site.

**Final answer from all the great (and quick) input here was this:**

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("zip-code", function(zip_code, element) {
    zip_code = zip_code.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || zip_code.length == 5 && zip_code.match(^606[0-9]{2}$);
}, "Please specify a City of Chicago Zip Code");
```

Comment: from memory `phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, "")` strips all space characters.

Comment: btw Jamie, because of the regex you dont need the .length == 5 as the regex will fail if it is not 5 digits anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

for the length use the [.length property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp)

```
if($('#dzip').val().length != 5)
  return false;
```

for the 606 use the [substr method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)

```
if($('#dzip').val().substr(0,3) != 606)
  return false;
```

combined

```
$('#dzip').change(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();
  if(val.length != 5 || val.substr(0,3) != 606)
    return false; //not valid
  else
  //do stuff here
})
```

---

**Try this:**

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("chicago", function(zip, element) {
    zip = zip.replace(/\s+/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || zip.match("^606[0-9]{2}$");
}, '**Recipient must reside in Chicago City Limits**');
```

The above code can be read as

- Add a method *chicago* to the *validator* plugin
- when the method is called strip all whitespace characters
- then if the field is not required and it is empty
- or if it is required and not empty and is 5 digits in length
- and the first 3 characters are 606
- return true
- else return false

Comment: Those are great Hailwood! But don't utilize the validate plugin, which is already hooked up into the form. Any idea how to translate that to the phone number example? Thanks for chiming in!

Comment: This was great. I love this place. With your bit and the regex from capsule this thread is answered!

Comment: This is the final solution marrying all the great feedback here: jQuery.validator.addMethod("zip-code", function(zip_code, element) {
  phone_number = zip_code.replace(/\s+/g, "");
  return this.optional(element) || zip_code.length == 6 && zip_code.match(^606[0-9]{2}$);
 }, "Please specify a City of Chicago Zip Code");

Comment: Can you update your block with Capsules regex and I can check you're as the answer for historical record :) I posted the combined bit in my thread.

Comment: Jamie, your line `phone_number = zip_code.replace(/\s+/g, "");` should read `zip_code = zip_code.replace(/\s+/g, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [jQuery plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/).

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: That's what I am using, just not sure how to write the zip code scenario into it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this regex "606[0-9][0-9]" and see if it can be matched. then you check whether the input is five digits since i think this regex will also match 606111.

Comment: "^606[0-9]{2}$" if you want 2 digits after 606

Comment: Brilliant Capsule! Just the piece I needed to finish fudging this together.