# javascript validation on array not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I've read through many posts, and tried various options, but my validation check on my JavaScript doesn't seem to be running.

I used this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490169/zipcode-validation-that-shows-an-error-for-particular-states) to try and write a validation check to see if the entered zip code is one one delivered to, but when I run it nothing happens and neither alert shows up.  Any help is appreciated.

This is the JavaScript I was using:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function validateZip() {
  var zipCode = $("#zipCode").val();
  var acceptableZipCodes = ["78205","72215","78212",];

if( $.inArray( zipCode, acceptableZipCodes)){
  alert("Yes, we can help!");
    }else{
  alert("Sorry, we don't deliever to your area yet.");
}
}
</script>
```

This is the form

```
<form name="zipForm" onsubmit="return(validateForm(zipCode))">
  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode"> 
    <input id="user_info" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: [How to add an event handler with jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/)

Comment: are you getting any error in your browser developer console?

Answer (score 1):

```
function validateZip() {
  var zipCode = document.zipForm.zipCode.value;
  var acceptableZipCodes = ["78205","72215","78212",];

  for (i = 0; i < cars.acceptableZipCodes.length; i++) { 
    if(acceptableZipCodes[i] == zipCode{
     alert("Yes, we can help!");
    }else{
     alert("Sorry, we don't deliever to your area yet.");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an ID instead of name attribute for your form tag (for a quicker retrieval).

```
<form id="zipForm">
   <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode"> 
   <input id="user_info" type="submit">
</form>
```

Then below, I would do this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  // add an event handler to your form (look at adeneo's comment)
  $('#zipForm').on('submit', function(e) {
      // prevent form from submitting
      e.preventDefault();
      // call your function
      validateZip($("#zipCode").val());
  });

  function validateZip(zipCode) {
    var acceptableZipCodes = ["78205", "72215", "78212"];
    // be careful with using $.inArray as the return value for no 
    // matches is -1 (and not false)
    if ($.inArray(zipCode, acceptableZipCodes) != -1) {
      alert("Yes, we can help!");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, we don't deliever to your area yet.");
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 mistakes I found.
1, you define the function validateZip, but you didn't call it in the script.
2, inArray() function will be return the position of the value in the array, so when a value doesnt in the array, it will return -1.

I do some changes in the code.
Hope it help you.

```
<form name="zipForm" onsubmit="return(validateZip())">
  <input type="text" id="zipCode" name="zipCode"> 
    <input id="user_info" type="submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validateZip() {
  var zipCode = $("#zipCode").val();
  var acceptableZipCodes = ["78205","72215","78212",];

if( $.inArray( zipCode, acceptableZipCodes) !== -1){
  alert("Yes, we can help!");
    }else{
  alert("Sorry, we don't deliever to your area yet.");
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if it's begger than -1:

```
if($.inArray( zipCode, acceptableZipCodes) > -1)
```

Here a jsfiddle example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b042xzdd/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  I'll go in and add that as well